# Facebook like buttonto like a particular wall post (photo, video, link, etc) of my facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

How can I make Facebook like button on my web page to like a particular wall post/object (photo, video, link, etc) on my Facebook page when people click it?
I only get to make people to like my Facebook page, but not a particular post/object (photo, video, link, etc)
Does it make a sense?

Answer (score 0):

To acquire a LIKE button for a particular URL, you can get embed code from facebook developers site - It gives a menu where you can enter URL and edit settings for LIKE Button then once you click GET CODE after setting all properties, it gives you an Embed code that you can use to put that LIKE Button on your website:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/

Following is the example code for LIKE button - it will display a LIKE button for URL `www.google.com` - note the parameter `href=http://WWW.GOOGLE.COM` in code - This is for which will be LIKED.

`<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://WWW.GOOGLE.COM&amp;width=The+pixel+width+of+the+plugin&amp;height=80&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;layout=standard&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=true&amp;send=false&" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:The pixel width of the pluginpx; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>`